# How to Cast Object in Jpype Python

Tags: java, python, casting, jpype

I have a method which takes :   "java.io.Reader"  as argument
java.io.Reader is an Interface and cannot be instancied.

So, I use one sub class like this:
StringReader= jp.java.io.StringReader("teststring")

How can I convert StringReader into java.io.Reader type ?

Because the method cannot do implicetely.

EDIT: I receive this error message when using the method:

```
   txt= u'gfdgfdgddf'
   StringReader = jp.JClass('java.io.StringReader')(txt)
   StringReader.ready()  #Ok works
   userDicC= jp.JClass('org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary')
   useDic= userDicC(StringReader)
```

Method details:
       public static UserDictionary open(Reader reader)
                           throws IOException

I got this error:

userDicC= java.jp.JClass('org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary')
useDic= userDicC(StringReader)

```
    line 84, in _javaInit
    self.__javaobject__ = self.__class__.__javaclass__.newClassInstance(*args)

   RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at  src\native\common\jp_method.cpp:121
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast the object?  What happens if you pass the `StringReader` to the method you say needs a `java.io.Reader`?

Comment: Because I received a error message:

Comment: And what was that error message?  Please edit your question to include this message.

Comment: What method are you calling?  What parameter types does it take and what values are you passing for any other parameters?  The reason I ask this is that I tried creating a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#BufferedReader%28java.io.Reader%29) from a `StringReader` and that worked.

Comment: I put the apache method in the code.

Comment: Looks to me like `useDic= userDicC(StringReader)` should be `useDic= userDicC.open(StringReader)`, i.e. you missed a call to the `open` method.

Comment: Thanks, it works.  Why I cannot use the constructor ?  public static UserDictionary open(Reader reader)    Because this is static ?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it turns out that the problem is not related to casting an object at all.

To call the method [`public static UserDictionary open(Reader reader)`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/analyzers-kuromoji/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ja/dict/UserDictionary.html#open%28java.io.Reader%29), you need to replace the line

```
useDic= userDicC(StringReader)
```

with

```
useDic= userDicC.open(StringReader)
```

The former line will not work because in version 5.5.0 of Lucene-Kuromoji the `UserDictionary` class declares no public constructors.  (The class does have a private constructor that takes a `List<String[]>` parameter and the static `open` method calls this.)

Confusingly, older versions of this class, such as that in version 5.0.0 of Lucene-Kuromoji, *do* declare a constructor that takes a single `Reader` parameter.  I would expect your code to have worked with that version of Lucene-Kuromoji.